# Search through RecyclerView using Searchview

Tags: android, searchview, android-recyclerview

I want to search through `RecyclerView`, I have `List<BaseOfCards>`  (BaseOfCards is my getter&setter class) 
My **RecyclerViewAdapter** :

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<BaseOfCards> items;

//private int itemLayout;
//String cardvalue;
private Activity mActivity;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Activity mActivity, Context context, List<BaseOfCards> items) {
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.items = items;
    //this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view, mActivity);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    BaseOfCards item = items.get(position);
    holder.title.setTag(item);
    holder.title.setText(item.getCardName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return items.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private Activity mActivity;
    TextView title;
    ImageView titileImageView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Activity mActivity) {

        super(itemView);

        titileImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_country);


        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        this.mActivity = mActivity;

    }
}

}
```

I add SearchView to my menu and initialize it in **MainActivity**:

```
 MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search1);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
```

What do I need to do next? Make my **RecyclerViewAdapter** `implement Filterable` or what? Or just make class `filter` in *RecyclerViewAdapter** and just call it from my **MainActivity** ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved my problem

1. Make my class **RecyclerViewAdapter** `implements Filterable`
2. Add line  `private List<BaseOfCards> orig;`
3. Add method `getFilter` in **RecyclerViewAdapter**

   ```
   public Filter getFilter() {
   return new Filter() {
       @Override
       protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
           final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
           final List<BaseOfCards> results = new ArrayList<BaseOfCards>();
           if (orig == null)
               orig  = items;
               if (constraint != null){
                   if(orig !=null & orig.size()>0 ){
                       for ( final BaseOfCards g :orig) {
                           if (g.getCardName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))results.add(g);
                       }
                   }
                   oReturn.values = results;
               }
               return oReturn;
           }

   @Override
       protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
           items = (ArrayList<BaseOfCards>)results.values;
           notifyDataSetChanged();

       }
   };
   ```
4. Make **MainActivity** `implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` and change method `onQueryTextChange` :

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
       if ( TextUtils.isEmpty ( newText ) ) {
           adapter.getFilter().filter("");
       } else {
           adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: Cool, I will add this functionality with that method (`getFilter`) in my https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter ;-)

Comment: I added that functionality, but it was more complicated than foreseen. Indeed now, I am not convinced to have that filter in the Adapter, *because* the Objects in the adapter are **already** a copy of something original coming from a source such as DB/XML/JSON in memory as domain object - The problem is not the filter but the add/del/mod you perform on a **filtered** list: All changes should also reflect in the "original" adapter list **AND** in the original source... At this point is more convenient to have a filtered copy list directly from the the source and update Adapter with that list.

Comment: If you are interested it is under Dev Branch: https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/tree/dev

Comment: what is `orig` and `items` here?

Comment: @RevanthRev orig and items are Lists of my items to filter

Comment: @Davidea. Your link is broken.

Comment: @anivaler and to everybody else: yes actually I've removed _dev_ branch, because not needed anymore for the library.  _Master_ branch is now the main reference. I use dev only for new development as it was the case in that period. Sorry for the inconvenient.

Comment: due to not defining  items your good example going bad i am giving you down vote for it

Comment: your code is working fine but how can i add multiple item search?

Comment: In this example `items` represent the main list in adapter or your data. `orig` is just the copy of the main list or copy of `items`. Also I would like to point out that if you are working with list of names you should change condition `if (g.getCardName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))` to `if (g.getCardName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))`

Comment: for large number of items it stuck while searching item.I have implemented same code.What should i do for this plz help

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to [ololoking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4470323/ololoking) answer.
In `MainActivity` we should also add next code so it would work:

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Thanks ololoking for your answer. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

[image: search through recyclerview]

In your adapter class extend filterable.
Then override the public Filter getFilter().

```
   @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

                if(charSequence == null | charSequence.length() == 0){
                    filterResults.count = getUserModelListFiltered.size();
                    filterResults.values = getUserModelListFiltered;

                }else{
                    String searchChr = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();

                    List<UserModel> resultData = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(UserModel userModel: getUserModelListFiltered){
                        if(userModel.getUserName().toLowerCase().contains(searchChr)){
                            resultData.add(userModel);
                        }
                    }
                    filterResults.count = resultData.size();
                    filterResults.values = resultData;

                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

                userModelList = (List<UserModel>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
        return filter;
      }
```

in your main activity add search view and listener to onQueryTextChange.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            usersAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });



    return  true;
}
```

Full tutorial and source code.
[Recyclerview with SearchView](https://youtu.be/ujKDN_ZtGHQ?sub_confirmation=1)

Answer (score 0):

Using an autocompletetextview or an edittext i handled this one as following where

```
 public List<SalesProductsItems> mItems
```

is the initial listitem instance and .

```
  public static List<SalesProductsItems> filteredIt
```

is the instance used in displaying items.Since the 1st time the filter results is not null the `mItems` instance will be equal to the `filteredIt` instance (thus loosing the initial list) then on the `publishResults` method right before `mItems` looses the original values, I'm equating it to the passed instance `originallist` . Hope it helps someone

```
private static class ProductsFilter extends Filter {

    private final SalesProductsAdapter adapter;

    private final List<SalesProductsItems> originalList;

    private final List<SalesProductsItems> filteredList;

    private ProductsFilter(SalesProductsAdapter adapter, List<SalesProductsItems> originalList) {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.originalList = new LinkedList<>(originalList);
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0)
            filteredList.addAll(originalList);
        else {
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (final SalesProductsItems it : originalList) {

                if (it.getProduct().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(it);
                }
            }
        }

        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        adapter.mItems = originalList;
        if(results.count > 0) {
            filteredIt.clear();
            filteredIt.addAll((ArrayList<SalesProductsItems>) results.values);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            filteredIt.clear();
            filteredIt.addAll(adapter.mItems);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the time the other positive answer was done, I've now implemented a **fast async filter** using `AsyncTask` in my [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter) library, performance are very good with big lists, having animations too!
The Adapter is configurable to enable/disable properties in filtering result to increase speed when necessary. Another big advantage is also that interface is still responding to the user.

Test done in my Samsung S3 running Android 6: with a starting list of 10.450 items, from the moment the background process starts it takes ~1s to filter a character and select 3.890 items.

I've done also a [Wiki page](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/wiki/5.x-%7C-Search-Filter) with all the details to use filter with the Adapter.

Comment: I am having same issue ,have you solved this issue.Please help me @Davidea

Comment: @SagarHudge, from the time of my previous comment to the accepted answer, my filter changed, the current way to filter is described in the wiki page. Space to do it better and similar with Filter class there is, but now that's the way with FlexibleAdapter.