# Search Item In Recyclerview,SearchView to filter a List of countries

Tags: android

A am new here,I am new to android,i have list of Countries that comes from fetching data from server, tried all solutions , nothing works,and I need to filter the fetched list, 
I have applyed this lesson 
[Search through RecyclerView using Searchview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697562/search-through-recyclerview-using-searchview?rq=1)

Any solution will be appreciated,
thanks in advance.

```
public class Cities extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private  RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static ArrayList<CitiesModel> cititesNames;
    private RecyclerViewUtils.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener showHideToolbarListener;

    private EditText mSearchView;
    private CitiesAdapter citiesAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cities);

        setRecycUp();
        getCities();


    }

    public void setRecycUp() {
        mSearchView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.city);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    }

    public void getCities() {
        JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Config.Root+ Config.FITCHCITIES, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                cititesNames=new ArrayList<CitiesModel>();


                for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject= (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                        CitiesModel citiesModel=new CitiesModel();

                        String CityName = jsonObject.getString("city");

                        citiesModel.setCity(CityName);


                        cititesNames.add(citiesModel);


                       adapter = new CitiesAdapter(Cities.this,cititesNames);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "time out Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authenticatin Failure Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"JSon Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        })
                ;

        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(arrayRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return true;
    }

}
```

This is My Adapter

```
public class CitiesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CitiesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<CitiesModel> dataSet;

    private static Context mCtx;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewCity;
        private  Activity mActivity;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView,Activity mActivity) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cities);
            mCtx = itemView.getContext();
            this.mActivity=mActivity;
        }
    }
    private  Activity mActivity;

    public CitiesAdapter(Activity mActivity,List<CitiesModel> data) {

        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mActivity=mActivity;

    }

    @Override
    public CitiesAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cities, parent, false);
        CitiesAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new CitiesAdapter.MyViewHolder(view,mActivity);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CitiesAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        CitiesModel citiesModel = dataSet.get(listPosition);

        TextView textViewcity = holder.textViewCity;
        textViewcity.setText(citiesModel.getCity().toString().trim());


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new
                                                   View.OnClickListener() {
                                                       @Override
                                                       public void onClick(View view) {
                                                           mCtx = holder.itemView.getContext();

                                                           String prodtype = dataSet.get(listPosition).getCity();
                                                           Intent type = new Intent(mCtx, SignUp.class);
                                                           type.putExtra("TYPE", prodtype);
                                                           mActivity.setResult(0, type);
                                                           mActivity.finish();

//                                                           Toast.makeText(mCtx,dataSet.get(listPosition).getCity(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                       }
                                                   });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return (null != dataSet ? dataSet.size() : 0);
    }

}
```

DataModel

```
public class CitiesModel {
        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        String city;
    }
```

Comment: You simply need to filter your data before you create the Adapter. Or even in the adapter after that- just remember to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: How are you wanting to filter it?  One time after you download the data?  Or do you want to be able to add and remove filters later on?  Very different answers for those two.

Comment: what i mean is to search about item in recyclerview by SearchView @ X3Btel