# how to add filter to RecyclerViewAdapter using kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, filter, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I want to add a filter to this RecyclerViewAdapter please help in this code

> NOTE : I USE A CLASS To fill the LIST ,this  Class TAkes four
>   parameters as INPUTS (three Strings and an Image (Int)).
>
> ```
> like the following example : 
>
>             booksList.add(Book("The Wild Robot", "A 2 Categorie Book", "Description book", R.drawable.thewildrobot))
>         booksList.add(Book("Maria Semples", "Categorie Book", "Description book", R.drawable.mariasemples))
> ```

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


@Suppress("UNREACHABLE_CODE")
class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val mContext: List_of_Books, private val mData: MutableList<Book>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    private var mFilteredList: MutableList<Book>? = null


   init {
        mFilteredList = mData
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mData.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val view: View
        val mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardveiw_item_book, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.tv_book_title.text = mData[position].getTitle()
        holder.img_book_thumbnail.setImageResource(mData[position].thumbnail)
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(mContext, Book_Activity::class.java)

            // passing data to the book activity
            intent.putExtra("Title", mData[position].getTitle())
            intent.putExtra("Description", mData[position].description)
            intent.putExtra("Thumbnail", mData[position].thumbnail)
            intent.putExtra("Category", mData[position].category)


            // start the activity
            mContext.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    fun setfilter(listitem: MutableList<Book>): MutableList<Book>? {
    mFilteredList!!.clear()
    /*mFilteredList = ArrayList()*/
    mFilteredList!!.addAll(listitem)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    return mFilteredList
}


    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        internal var tv_book_title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title_id) as TextView
        internal var img_book_thumbnail: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_img_id) as ImageView
        internal var cardView: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_id) as CardView

    }


}
```

When I write in the EdiText nothing is changing , i'm using this code for the Editext:

```
    fun filter(pl: MutableList<Book>, query: String): MutableList<Book> {
        var query = query
        query = query.toLowerCase()
        val filteredModeList = ArrayList<Book>()
        for (model in pl) {
            val text = model.getTitle()!!.toLowerCase()
            if (text.startsWith(query) || (text.contains(query))) {
                filteredModeList.add(model)
            }
        }
        return filteredModeList
    }
    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
    editText.hint = getString(R.string.Search_here)

    editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
           val filtermodelist = filter(booksList, p0.toString())
            myAdapter.setfilter(filtermodelist)

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }
    })
```

**BOOK CLASS**

```
import com.medanis.fneclisbooks.R.attr.title
import com.medanis.fneclisbooks.R.string.category
import com.medanis.fneclisbooks.R.string.description
import java.util.ArrayList
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty1
import android.R.attr.name



class Book(title: String, category: String, description: String, var thumbnail: Int) {

    private var title: String? = title
    var category: String? = category
    var description: String? = description

    fun getTitle(): String? {
        return title
    }

    fun setTitle(title: String) {
        this.title = title
    }}
```

> I THINK THE PROBLEM IS IN THE FILTER IN THE ADAPTER THERE IS SOMETHING
>   WRONG THERE PLEASE HELP ME TO FIX IT

Please Help me , and if you need any more informations let me know in comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search through RecyclerView using Searchview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697562/search-through-recyclerview-using-searchview)

Comment: don't use `myAdapter.filter(newText)` - that's still the initial text, you'll need the text that the function provides after change:  `myAdapter(p0?.toString())` which represents the text at that point in time

Comment: yes that's my bad but the problem is still the same please check the filter and the Book class if they are correct